# saving files outside the public folder with attachment_fu in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, attachment-fu

I'm using attachment_fu in a rails application to handle file uploads, and i want to save them in a directory in the root of the application called attachments.  however, I cannot seem to make this plugin save a file in any other directory than public. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

thx

-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something a la?

```
has_attachment :storage => :file_system, :path_prefix => 'attachments/'
```

Comment: yeah, i've tried several combinations of path_prefix options, and none seem to work unless they start with 'public/'. here's what i get from that option when i try to upload a file :
No such file or directory - /storage/daisi/branches/development/public//storage/daisi/branches/development/attachments/0000/0007/524_IMS.yml

Comment: Strange. I suppose you could always just create an alias in the public directory to a directory at the application root level.

I suppose on some level this makes sense though. The web server (whatever it may be) only really knows about the 'public/' directory so all static files need to be included there within. When you upload a file, it needs to be in the 'public/' directory to be addressable via URL.

That said, I'm sure there are cases where you might want to upload a file and make it not addressable via URL.

Comment: i actually feel kind of dumb for asking this question now, because i realized that my problem wasn't the plugin itself, but some other code in the file class that the public directory hard-coded in the method that reads the file data in (these are all .yml files). So, your solution is actually correct.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved. For a second there, I'd talked myself out of my own answer :-P